# Make window pop up in the same browser

Tags: jquery

I wanted to make a window popup in the same browser blocking the background..I am a newbie and does not have any idea about it.. can anyone help me out with this ??

Also Can this be done with accordion in jquery ?? or should i use some other technology for my window to pop up ??

Comment: Can you explain how/why you want to use an accordion?

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI has a dialog box with an option for modal (which is what you're referring to with "blocking out the background", I believe).

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean a modal window?
See this  http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Answer (score 1):

May be you are asking for Lightbox, 
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/